# How can I add the multiselct function based on Bootstrap version 2.2.2?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am working with an old version of Bootstrap 2.2.2. Do not offer to update, the rest of the necessary advantages may fly off on other pages.

I tried the plugins Chosen and Bootstrap Multiselect, but it didn't help.

Chosen: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Bootstrap Multiselect: https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: maybe try using select2 plugin https://select2.org/

Comment: Select2 is not compatible with this version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.